# Tensorflow getting error in fit function for my model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory

I´m training a model to predict a class of images 0 or 1, is a CNN net. When I´m trying to fit the model always get this error:

> ValueError: Shapes (None,) and (None, 60, 36, 2) are incompatible

```py
input_shape = (60, 36, 3)

# define two sets of inputs
inputA = Input(shape=input_shape)
inputB = Input(shape=input_shape)

x = Dense(8, activation="relu")(inputA)
x = Dense(4, activation="relu")(x)
x = keras.Model(inputs=inputA, outputs=x)

y = Dense(64, activation="relu")(inputB)
y = Dense(32, activation="relu")(y)
y = Dense(4, activation="relu")(y)
y = keras.Model(inputs=inputB, outputs=y)

combined = concatenate([x.output, y.output])

z = Dense(2, activation="relu")(combined)
z = Dense(2, activation="sigmoid")(z)

prediction=Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(z)

model = keras.Model(inputs=[x.input, y.input], outputs=[prediction])


model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-3),  
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(
  train_generator,
  steps_per_epoch=25,
  epochs=20,
  validation_data=dev_generator,
  validation_steps=5,
  verbose=2
)
```

Error:

ValueError: in user code:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1021, in train_function  *
    return step_function(self, iterator)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1010, in step_function  **
    outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1000, in run_step  **
    outputs = model.train_step(data)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 860, in train_step
    loss = self.compute_loss(x, y, y_pred, sample_weight)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 919, in compute_loss
    y, y_pred, sample_weight, regularization_losses=self.losses)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/compile_utils.py", line 201, in __call__
    loss_value = loss_obj(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=sw)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/losses.py", line 141, in __call__
    losses = call_fn(y_true, y_pred)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/losses.py", line 245, in call  **
    return ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/losses.py", line 1790, in categorical_crossentropy
    y_true, y_pred, from_logits=from_logits, axis=axis)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/backend.py", line 5083, in categorical_crossentropy
    target.shape.assert_is_compatible_with(output.shape)

ValueError: Shapes (None,) and (None, 60, 36, 2) are incompatible
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: You need some Flatten layers, you should consider how Dense layers with with multiple inputs dimensions.

Comment: Can you give some info on what `train_generator` returns?

Comment: Yes, you might want to flatten the input of 60,36,2 using the Flatten() layer.

Comment: please, clarify what's your task and the ideas behind your architecture because otherwise is hard to follow the code. It's strange that your input's shape corresponds to an image but then you apply a `Dense` layer. In addition to this, it seems that you're using two inputs. Why? and finally, your training generator is not mentioned in your question. Please, tell at least what it generates

Comment: The input shape defined in the very first line is input_shape = (60, 36, 3) . In the Dense function, the shape given is 2. Hence the error of incompatible shapes. Please change the Dense function to get the error sorted.